# How to avoid using pointers/typedefs in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style

Whenever I write C++ code, I always end up using pointer types and -> to reference member functions. Is there anyway for me to avoid code that looks like this:

```
typedef Node *NodeRef;
typedef Graph *GraphRef;

Node{
     vector<NodeRef> nodeList;
};



Graph{
     vector<NodeRef> list;
};

    Node::Node(){
        nodeList.push_back(this);
    }

NodeRef n = new NodeRef();
n->someMemberFunction();
n->someOtherMemberFuction()->aThirdMemberFunction();
```

Is it possible for me to use `.` for member access, and use the original object type or a reference instead of the typedef pointer type?

Comment: You could do `(*n).someMemberFunction();`

Comment: There is no reason to do what you ask. Just use `->`, there's nothing wrong with it. If you think it's weird, what you're asking for is more weird.

Comment: Okay. I'll just use the ->, it just confuses me because the STL all uses `.` notation and references.

Comment: @StevenMorad The standard library uses objects by value, not references, most of the time. And you should as well - only resort to pointers and dynamic allocation when you need to.

Comment: `NodeRef` is a misleading name a pointer to `Node`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NodeRef n = new NodeRef();
```

This won't even compile, I assume you meant to use `new Node()`

1) Why are you using `new` anyway?  What's wrong with just doing this:

```
Node n;
n.someMemberFunction();
```

Tada! Now you don't have a pointer.

If you don't want to need a pointer here:

```
n.someOtherMemberFuction()->aThirdMemberFunction();
```

Then simply don't return a pointer from `someOtherMemberFunction()`.

2) If you must use `new` then **use a smart pointer to own the object**:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> n(new Node);
```

If you don't do this kittens will die and blood will rain from the sky.

If you can't use `std::unique_ptr` then use `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`.

3) You can create a reference to the object the pointer points to:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> np(new Node);
Node& n = *np;
n.someMemberFunction();
n.someOtherMemberFuction()->aThirdMemberFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

well, first... there's nothing wrong with pointers. But, you can always use [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29).

References allow you to use `.` instead of `->`. There are more differences than that... but look at it and you will see. ;)

Comment: So how would I create a simple Graph with a reference?

`Graph& g = new Graph();` gives me the error `No suitable constructor from Graph* to Graph`. `new` is supposed to return a reference, no?

Comment: "Create" a constructor? Do you mean call it or what? Not quite sure about your question. Chek the link I gave, it should make it clear for you.

Comment: Here's a complete program to illustrate inquam's comment: `struct graph {
 void f() {}
};
int main() {
 graph& g = *new graph;
 g.f();
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @JoshGreifer, dereferencing the return value of `new` is punishable by death where I come from. That's a really bad habit to introduce someone to.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that you need to acquire a good book on C++. No offense intended of course, but new and delete and pointers vs. references is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I know,  I was too lazy to create a pointer var :/